# How to return a MySQL string from within a PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to reuse the same MySQL query, so thought wrapping it in PHP function might help. I did it as follows:

```
function fetch_from_db($criteria) {
    global $wpdb;
    $qvar = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy where $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = %s", $criteria);
    return $qvar;
}
$get_two_wheeler_make = fetch_from_db('2-wheeler-make');
```

but things are not working and it is returning `null`. How do I make it work? What is wrong in the code?

Comment: What happens if you change "select * from $wpdb->terms... into something like: "select * from ".$wpdb->terms.".......?

Comment: @ThatMSG I get `array(0) {}`

Comment: @ThatMSG `$wpdb->get_results("select * from" . $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy . "where" . $wpdb->terms.term_id . "=" . $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy . "=" . $criteria);`

Comment: Dont forget to keep the spaces: $wpdb->get_results("select * from " . $wpdb->terms.", ".$wpdb->term_taxonomy . " where " . $wpdb->terms.term_id . " = " . $wpdb->term_taxonomy.".".term_taxonomy_id." and ".$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy . " = %s" , $criteria);

Comment: @ThatMSG `and` does not need double quotes. I geave spaces everywhere else. Now I am getting result back but it is fetching all the result in the table. It doesnt consider $criteria at all that is passed to the function

Comment: @ThatMSG I just inserted plain text instead of $criteria, everything inside quotes, it works perfectly, but the variable is not working. If I put some string instead of $criteria, then it works, but variable is not passed properly

Comment: I edited my answer, `$criteria` needs to be handled like a sting in the the statement; therefore, wrapped in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a great resource [Class Reference $wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).  The `,` is making you `$criteria` the object type being return, not the search criteria; therefore, `%s` is empty.  Add `$criteria` to the query string.  And try again.

```
$qvar = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy
   WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
   AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '".$criteria."'");
```

Comment: I just inserted plain text instead of $criteria, everything inside quotes, it works perfectly, but the variable is not working

Comment: following is working fine `$qvar  = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy where $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '2-wheeler-make'");` but, instead of that 2-wheeler-make I put $criteria and pass the variable from function then it doesnt work. Otherwise it works even without any hacks

Comment: Thank you very much. That last one worked! Yes it should have been handled like a string. Will mark this as correct answer!

Comment: for security should I do something about $criteria or does WP_Query handles it?

Comment: It is always safe to assume the worst.  I would look into the wpdb class and see how it is handled.  I know get_results() is passed to wpdb query.  I would look there.

Comment: In the resource I linked it explains using prepare() and protection against injection attacks.